# Trying to implement 3d autoencoder like algorithm that maps an image to a video but mismatch at output dimensions

Tags: python, autoencoder

I am trying to map a single image to a whole video using an autoencoder like architecture, but insteaad the o ne end will have the image , while the output will be the video. There is a mismatch in the dimesnions expected by the algorithm and the actual dimensions of the video. Each video has dimensions(4500,144,256,3) here is my code:

````
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')) #28 x 28 x 32
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')) #28 x 28 x 32
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) #14 x 14 x 32
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')) #14 x 14 x 64
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) #7 x 7 x 64
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')) #7 x 7 x 128 (small and thick)

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(3*6*6*6,activation='relu'))
model.add(Reshape((3,6,6,6)))
model.add(Conv3D(8, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2)))

model.add(Conv3D(8, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2)))

model.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2)))


model.add(Conv3D(3, (3, 3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
model.compile(optimizer="adadelta", loss='binary_crossentropy')```

and here is the error message

>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-afa431bc2efe> in <module>()
    249 
    250 
--> 251 video_proc()
    252 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    139                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    140                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 141                             str(data_shape))
    142     return data
    143 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv3d_37 to have shape (96, 192, 192, 3) but got array with shape (4500, 144, 256, 3)>
````

Answer (score 0):

I changed the dimensions of the dense layer to

```
model.add(Dense(542*18*32*1,activation='relu'))
model.add(Reshape((542,18,32,1)))
model.add(Conv3D(8, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2)))

model.add(Conv3D(8, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2)))


model.add(Conv3D(3, (3, 3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
model.compile(optimizer="adadelta", loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

That gave me an output of ((4336,144,256,3))  then i adjusted the padding of the video to make it fit.